# How to move directory from one server to other?

Tags: ssh, unix, migration

I have SSH access to the both servers, one of them is empty. How can I move site directory from old server to new server via SSH connection?

PS: On both servers is unix

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My favorite is `rsync`. It is smart enough to copy only what has to be copied (i.e. changed or new).

```
rsync -avz /source/path user@desthost:/destination/path/
```

Note the final `/` at the end to ask rsync to copy *inside* that path (not over it).
`rsync` takes care of managing the ssh connection for you. The `avz` (typical) options ask `rsync` to use the *archive* (tar) mode, in order to copy recursively, and keep as much as possible date and user values. The `v` option is *verbose* to show you what is currently happening. The `z` option will zip (compress) the transfer to hopefully save time and bandwidth.

`rsync` is very powerful and is used by most professionals, however you may want to test it first using non valuable data to ensure the path and options match the requirements.

If you need to use rsync via SSH on a non-standard port like 2222, you can use the following command ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549945/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-different-ssh-port-when-using-rsync/4630407#4630407)):

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2222' /source/path user@desthost:/destination/path/
```

Comment: I think rsync is a better solution than ssh for the reason that ring0 has given, i.e it only copies what needs to be copied.
So if you need to do this more than once rsync will give you an advantage over straight scp.

Comment: rsync is definitly the tool. But about the trailing slash: this is important for the source not for the destination: rsync -a /src/ /dest
copies everything under src in dest, rsync -a /src /dest copies src and everything under it to dest/src/.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [tar pipe](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3152/copy-via-tar-pipe-while-preserving-file-permissions-run-this-command-as-root).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an well working answer in another question. It uses SSH-Agent to move a mysql dump: [Fastest way to move multiple databases to a new server](https://serverfault.com/questions/163305/fastest-way-to-move-multiple-databases-to-a-new-server/163320#163320)

Combine this with the answer of jscott